# How to use $lookup in aggregate to populate a field that references multiple models?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have this model:

```
const HistorySchema = new Schema({
  belongs_to: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    refPath: "onModel",
  },
  onModel: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["videos", "help_requests"],
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});
```

I want to use aggregate to populate `belongs_to` field. The problem is that with `aggregate` I have to specify which model `belongs_to` is referencing:

```
const populate_belongs_to_field_option = {
  $lookup: {
    // Here I should specify the model
    // But, it can be any of the model in the field
    // onModel
    // This returns an empty array
    // Which makes sense since onModel is not a model
    from: "onModel",
    localField: "belongs_to",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "belongs_to",
  },
};

const pipeline = [
  populate_belongs_to_field_option,
];
const history_events_with_aggregate = await History.aggregate(pipeline);
```

but `belongs_to` can reference either `"videos"` or `"help_requests"`. So I am not sure how to make this work.

Comment: i don't think it is possible to reference the collection name from collection's internal field.